# extjs contextmenu click, pass parent grid as parameter to controller method

Tags: extjs, parameter-passing, listener

Inside my extjs grid, when I right click I call a context menu.  When I click on one of the items I want to launch a method in the controller.  This all works successfully, problem is I want to pass the parent grid that this is being called from into the controller method.  Can someone please show me how to do this?

This is my context menu

```
Ext.define('Example.ContextMenuTradematch', {
xtype: 'contextMenuTradematch',
extend: 'Ext.menu.Menu',
items: [
    {
        text: 'Match Trade',
        iconCls: 'greenIcon',
        listeners: {
            click: {                    
                fn: 'onMatchTrade',
                params: {
                    param1: this
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Delete Trade',
        iconCls: 'deleteIcon',
        listeners: {
            click: 'onDeleteTrade'
        }
    }
]
```

});

then this is my controller method

```
    onMatchTrade: function (event, target, options) {
    debugger;
    var me = this;
```

How can I access the grid that the event originated from?

--and this is how I add the context menu to the grid

```
                    title: 'Tradematch Results: UNMATCHED',
                xtype: 'grid',
                itemId: 'gridUnmatchedId',
                ui: 'featuredpanel-framed',
                cls: 'custom-grid',
                margin: '0px 10px 0px 10px',
                flex: 2,
                width: '100%',
                bind: {
                    store: '{myTM_ResultsStore}'
                },
                listeners: {
                    itemcontextmenu: 'showContextMenuTradematch'
                },
```

and this is how the controller adds it...

```
    getContextMenu: function (cMenu) {
    if (!this.contextMenu) {
        debugger;
        this.contextMenu = this.getView().add({ xtype: cMenu });
    }
    return this.contextMenu;
},

showContextMenuTradematch: function (view, rec, node, index, e) {
    e.stopEvent();
    e.stopEvent();
    debugger;
    this.getContextMenu('contextMenuTradematch1').show().setPagePosition(e.getXY());
    return false;
},
```

Comment: How does the grid create to the controller? There's not enough contextual information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is when you create your `Example.ContextMenuTradematch` instance - that I'm assuming you do from a `itemcontextmenu` listener - then you could pass a reference to the grid.

```
itemcontextmenu: function (grid, record, item) {
     // code to create your menu
     // probably something like: 
     if (!grid.contextMenu) {
          grid.contextMenu = Ext.create('Example.ContextMenuTradematch', {
              ownerGrid: grid
          });
     }

     grid.contextMenu.showBy(item);
}
```

If `onMatchTrade` was fired by clicking on an `Ext.menu.Item` instance then it's signature will be:

```
onMatchTrade: function (item, e) {
    var menu = item.up('menu'),
        grid = menu.ownerGrid;

     console.log(grid);
}
```

There was a lot of guessing here. If this is not how you are creating your menu or calling the methods, adding a fiddle with the issue would help.

Here is a fiddle to use as template: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24fc

Comment: I added more details on how I am adding the menu to grid.  The only reason I chose this way is because thats the only way I was able to figure it out.  I am open to a better way

Comment: I tried the way you are doing it and I think I'll use it... seems to be cleaner.  One problem though, the context menu shows itself far away from the clicked button.  I fixed this on my previous way by the following line...this.contextMenu = this.getView().add({ xtype: 'contextMenuTradematch2' }).show().setPagePosition(e.getXY());  any idea how I can do that same thing with your example?

Comment: Yes, just use `grid.contextMenu.showAt(e.getX(), e.getY())`. I've updated the fiddle.